# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in wordpress wp-admin login

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I am using WordPress 4.9.2 and have followed all the steps for installation.

Now, once the installation finished I tried to login using entered credentials.

But its redirecting me to same wp-login.php page again and again.
I tried 'Lost your password?' option but haven't received any email yet.

Also, since my website uses SSL, I entered 'siteurl' and 'home' values with 'https://example.com/blog' but it doesn't even load wp-login.php then and as soon as I change it to 'http://example.com/blog' it loads the login page but after submission get redirected to same page.

Below are the few things I tried to get it resolved.

1. added below code in wp-config.php

   ```
   define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
   ```
2. disabled all plugins by renaming plugin folder
3. removed .htaccess file
4. restored default .htaccess file
5. added below code in wp-config.php

   ```
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
     $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
   ```
6. changed wp-login.php permission to 644

After every change , have cleared cache, cookies and checked again but no success.

Comment: Do you have access to your Apache / nginx config?

Comment: No. But you can suggest options so that I can communicate with the concerned person

Comment: 1. Is site serving front end pages e.g. home page by either a) HTTP, or b) HTTPS successfully? 2. Is the SSL cert installed on your server? 3. If not then who/what is providing SSL cert/ "HTTPS access"?

Comment: 1. front page is loading properly with https
2.Yes, SSL cert is installed

Answer (score 1):

If "your" SSL cert is provided by say an intermediate e.g. a CDN: Then the intermediary might be passing a "non-standard" 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' value e.g. uppercase "HTTPS" .

Alter your wp-config check of 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' to cater for these possibilities e.g.

`if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)`
`$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';`

Comment: Tried but no change

Comment: I am amending my answer (for others) but it won't help you. I'll add a few comments to your question requesting info that may help others solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, try to find the bug comes from.
1. take backup of DB & then drop all tables.
2. re-install WordPress by remaining all files as it is.
--> if still shows the same issue then the problem comes from file structure.
& 
if it works correctly then the issue comes from DB for URL mismatch.
Give your feedback about issue tracing process, so I can suggest you an accurate solution.

Comment: didn't get your point , pls explain
2. re-install WordPress by remaining all files as it is.

Comment: drop all tables, just let it database as empty & then fire front URL again which shows you to install WordPress again.

Comment: tried as per your suggestions but same situation. what can be the problem with file structure?

Answer (score 0):

similary i tried all the solutions like :

1. clearing browser cache
2. editting .htaccess and adding below lines

   define ('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');

   define ('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
3. renaming plugins

but none worked for me.

check your SSL if you are using cloudflare.

i was having problem accessing the dashboard by ftp filezilla , so i used my hosting providers cpanel.

fianlly , by putting the below code in wp-config.php worked for me.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; ``
```

I hope it helps, thank you.